# WPF WebBrowser - built-in search dialog doesn't work if content was loaded with NavigateToString

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, navigation, webbrowser-control

I use WebBrowser to display generated XML. My XML string loaded into browser by call to NavigateToString:

```
var text = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" 
         + Environment.NewLine
         + "<whatever/>";
Browser.NavigateToString(text);
```

After browser loads string content I'm trying to search for any displayed text using standard Ctrl+F search dialog - but it always shows warning "No matches found".

If I save the XML string to a file and use Browser.Navigate(filename) it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of concatenate the strings, use the `StringBuilder` class, not sure if that will solve your problem, but it's worth a try.

Comment: what if you wrap the string in html tags, `Browser.NavigateToString(string.Format("<html>{0}</html>", text));`

Comment: @Tico Thanks for StringBuilder hint, but here I was trying to keep sample code very simple, to attract attention to NavigateToString method.

Comment: @Tico Using StringBuilder will obviously not solve this problem. You may also want to take a look into the Remarks section of the [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) class documentation on MSDN to get an idea when its usage is appropriate and when *not*.

Comment: If you read my remarks you'll see that I did not suggest that it would solve the problem. String concatenation is not appropriate is it?..

Comment: @sa_ddam213 wrapping text with <html> doesn't help at all - browser shows empty page.

Comment: If I was unclear with my answer, I'll try to elaborate here. You will **not be able** to render **XML** with `NavigateToString`. You're going to have to convert it to **HTML** first (e.g., with an XSLT transform).

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to a file, the `WebBrowser` control performs MIME-type sniffing (often using the  file extension as a hint). Then it creates an [Active Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx9c54kf.aspx) object of the corresponding type. Most often it's an instance of [MSHTML Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but can also be an XML, PDF or Word document, all of which support Active Document interfaces.

Now, when you navigate to a string with `NavigateToString`, the `WebBrowser` doesn't make any attempts to recognize the document type, and simply creates and instance of MSHTML Document (rather than XML Document), then tries to parse the content as HTML and fails.

I don't think you can get the desired behavior using `NavigateToString`, and I believe the same applies to `NavigateToStream`. To illustrate what's going on, take your XML content and save it as `filename.html`, `filename.txt` and `filename.xml`. Try opening each file with IE.

On a side note, when you navigate to a URL, the server actually has an option to suggest the MIME type, using HTTP headers. The browser may or may not tolerate such suggestion (it will still perform some validation checks).

**The bottom line**: you will not be able to render XML with `NavigateToString` or `NavigateToStream`. You're going to have to convert it to HTML first (e.g., with an XSLT transform).

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. 
There is even the possibility to open the xml file directly using the overload:

```
webbrowser.Navigate(string filepathToXML)
```

Going this way, the builtin search panel works like a charm.